Heroku adding undefined before api ; undefiled/api
I deployed app on heroku and got an error in logs saying:
2024-04-09T05:34:19.728228+00:00 heroku[router]:
at=info
method=GET
path="/undefined/api/clinics"
host=dental-w-032fe80aafac.herokuapp.com
request_id=e1b0b541-b277-4569-9dc5-5a473667f9bd
fwd="77.240.35.7"
dyno=web.1
connect=0ms
service=2ms
status=200
bytes=964
protocol=https

Somehow, it adds undefined before api, but in code there is no vars before api and in heroku config there is also nothing, it only got: ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, MONGODB_URI: and REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET. And my connection with db works fine because my users can login or logout.
Code in front end where I try to get clinics:
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchClinics = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://dental-w-032fe80aafac.herokuapp.com/api/clinics');
      setClinics(response.data)
  
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
  fetchClinics()
}, [])

index.js:
app.use('/api', require('./routes/authRouter'));

const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

app.use(express.static(buildPath));

// create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return {
      filename: `${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    };
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: 'Welcome to the server' });
});

// Multer Middleware for file upload
app.post('/api/clinics', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  const rating = Number((Math.random() * (5 - 3.5) + 3.5).toFixed(1))
  let newClinic = new Clinic({
      name: req.body.name, 
      address: req.body.address,
      doctor: req.body.doctor,    
      price: req.body.price, 
      rating,
      image: { // store file data
          id: req.file.id,
          contentType: req.file.contentType,
          filename: req.file.filename
      }
  });

  newClinic.save()
      .then(clinic => res.json(clinic))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error:' + err));
});

// Route for serving images
app.get('/api/image/:filename', async (req, res) => {

  const { filename } = req.params;
  let image = imageCache.get(filename);

  // Load from the cache if possible
  if (image) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', image.contentType); 
    res.send(image.buffer);
    return;
  }

  try {
      await client.connect();
      const db = client.db("test"); 
      const bucket = new GridFSBucket(db, {
          bucketName: "fs" 
      });

      const downloadStream = bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(filename);
      let chunks = [];
      downloadStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });

      downloadStream.on('end', () => {
        let buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        let imageObject = {
          contentType: 'image/jpeg',
          buffer
        };
        // Cache the image
        imageCache.set(filename, imageObject);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', imageObject.contentType); 
        res.send(buffer);
      });

  } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(404).send('Image not found');
  }
});

Also, when I navigate to /api/clinics, I can see array of clinics from db:
// routes/authRouter.js
router.get('/clinics', authCtrl.getClinics);
router.post('/clinics', authCtrl.createClinics);

authCtrl.js:
const Clinic = require('../models/clinicsModel')
const authCtrl = {
  getClinics : async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const clinics = await Clinic.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 });
      res.json(clinics);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send('An error occurred while fetching the clinics.');
    }
  },

  createClinics : async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const {name, address, medicalWorker} = req.body;
    
      if (!name || !address || !medicalWorker) {  
        return res.status(400).json({message: 'Bad request: name, medicalWorker, and address are required'});
      }
    
      const image = req.file ? req.file.filename : null;
      const newClinic = new Clinic({name, medicalWorker, address, image});
      const savedClinic = await newClinic.save();
    
      res.json(savedClinic);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({message: 'Server error. Please try again later.'});
    }
  },
}

I have tried to change to relative urls, or some CORS settings and some proxy in front end code:
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "https://dental-w-032fe80aafac.herokuapp.com",
  "private": true,
  ...
}


Got an answer, just need to rebuild project manually, npm run build.
and it will fix the issue that heroku adds undefined before /api
